# How to see the user's reputation graph?

Tags: discussion, reputation, profile-page, reputation-graph

My browser displays the user reputation in [the user's *Activity* page](https://askubuntu.com/users/current) without a graph:

> [image: screenshot of reputation section without a graph]

How can I display the user reputation with a graph, as shown in the image below?

> [image: screenshot of reputation section with a graph]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three options:

1. Lower your browser's zoom level (I had to reduce it to 90% because I had *Hide left navigation* disabled in [profile *Settings*](https://askubuntu.com/users/preferences/)).
2. Enable *Hide left navigation* in your [profile *Settings*](https://askubuntu.com/users/preferences/) so you can see the graph at 100% zoom.
3. Use a monitor that has a higher resolution.

**Source:** [The reputation graph disappears when zooming in past 100%](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415576/the-reputation-graph-disappears-when-zooming-in-past-100).

Comment: I don't think that the behavior described in the linked SO post has actually changed. What [Oleg Valter's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/415580/3140225) essentially says is that the profile page is responsive, hence changes depending on the window width/screen resolution. On my 1920x1080 screen with the browser window maximized, I am able to zoom up to 150% and still be able to see the reputation graph.

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog That makes sense, I'm at 1280x720. I edited my answer.